# Conditionals in WP_Query

Tags: wp-query, conditional-tags

What I'm trying to do is this:

If in the last 7 days someone has added a post in the category 'featured' display it in the loop. Otherwise, display the most commented post from the last seven days.

So far I can display the most commented post but I'm not sure how to go about setting up the if/else block or if there is built in functionality in the wordpress core.

```
<?php 


   // retrieve posts from the last seven days

    function filter_where( $where = '' ) {
        // posts in the last 7 days
        $where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-7 days')) . "'";
        return $where;
    }



                    $args = array(
                    'posts_per_page' => 1,
                    'orderby' => 'comment_count'
                    );

                    add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );

                    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

                    remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );



                    ?>

                    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

                    <?php $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID; ?>

                        <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><h1 class="main-heading"><?php the_title(); ?></h1></a>
                        <p class="meta">Published on <?php the_date(); ?> by <a href="<?php echo the_permalink();?>"><?php the_author(); ?></a><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"> <?php comments_number(); ?></a></p>

                        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

                        <hr>

                    <?php endwhile; else: ?>


                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: You can probably use `pre_get_posts` and run your conditionals there. [View The Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify things by using the [`date_query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters) of `WP_Query()`, instead of the `posts_where` filter.

You can then try the following (untested):

```
// Fetch from the 'featured' category
$args = array(                
    'posts_per_page' => 1,                    
    'category_name'  => 'featured',
    'date_query'     => array( array( 'after' => '1 week ago' ) ),
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( 0 === $the_query->found_posts )
{
    // Fetch the most commented post
    $args = array(                
        'posts_per_page' => 1,                    
        'orderby'        => 'comment_count',
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
}

// Your loop here:

if( $the_query->have_posts() ) : 
    while( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
        // ...
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
else:
    _e( 'No posts found!' );
endif;
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on date_query, makes it easier if I change the time and date in wordpress admin.

Comment: yes, the date query can be very handy - ps: I updated the answer to add a missing array for the date query.